# How to insert a default image into database when the path is null?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing one problem which when I want to insert image into the database but the path is null then I will like a default picture to be insert into the default. Can this be possible???

```
 if (imageName != "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(imageName);
                    //Initialize a file stream to read the image file
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    //Initialize a byte array with size of stream
                    byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fs.Length];
                    //Read data from the file stream and put into the byte array
                    fs.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fImage", imgByteArr);
                }
                else {
                    imageName = @"/HouseWivesSavior;component/images/unknown.jpg";
                    //Initialize a file stream to read the image file
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    //Initialize a byte array with size of stream
                    byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fs.Length];
                    //Read data from the file stream and put into the byte array
                    fs.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fImage", imgByteArr);
                    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fImage", "");

                }
```

Comment: Why even insert a default image into the database? It takes a lot of space, moreover, the same BLOB file would be repeated for a lot of rows. If you're using Oracle, you could use deduplication to avoid this, but still it is a really bad idea to store a default image instead of a null. We can surely replace this null with an image at the front end at run-time.

Comment: Thank you Guy ... I figure out with this code:As my data type in database is Varbinary(MAX):

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName))
                {
                    //Insert image into database
                }
                else
                {

                    //Else inser null into the database
                    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@fImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);

                    cmdInsert.Parameters["@fImage"].Value = DBNull.Value;

                }

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Why would you bother keeping a default image in the database? This is expensive in terms of storage and network traffic. Imagine having 1024 records with the same default image of 200KB, you will be wasting 200MB of db storage. Not only that, retrieving BLOBs from a database is a very expensive operation.

Avoid it, if the path is null then insert exactly that, a null value. Then let your business logic decide what to do when there's not image.

And by the way, never check for empty strings like you did in your question. Use the IsNullOrEmpty static method of the string object instead

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName))
```

That will evaluate for null and empty values more efficiently

Hope it helps

Leo

Comment: Thank you Guy ... I figure out with this code:As my data type in database is Varbinary(MAX):

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName))
                {
                    //Insert image into database
                }
                else
                {

                    //Else inser null into the database
                    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@fImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);

                    cmdInsert.Parameters["@fImage"].Value = DBNull.Value;

                }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for an empty string, check for null.

```
var imagePath = string.Empty;

if (imageName == null)
    imagePath = "pathToDefaultImage";
else
    imagePath = "pathToNonDefaultImage"

... do your work here using imagePath as the path
```

But you could just save null in your database. And then when you're loading your images from your database, just set a default image when you encounter null. That way you're not saving the same default image over and over.